# Boot menu won't appear after continuous pressing of F2 and F12 keys - Dell Inspirion 7537

Tags: boot, windows-8.1, dell-inspiron

I installed windows 8.1 in legacy boot. After that when I tried to access the boot menu by pressing F2 and F12 but it constantly takes me to the windows. I also tried using different keys like DEL, F8. But no Luck!.
Is this a hardware issue or a software issue.

Comment: With Windows 8 they changed how you access this menu.  You can either indicate you want to boot to it from within Windows or you will automatically access it after 3 failed attempts to access Windows.  This was done because Windows 8 now starts up nearly instantaneously.  *Even if you are booting to a MBR partition this is still the case.*

Comment: Isn't the Windows 8 power thing because it goes into a hybrid shutdown/hibernate... hence why it boots back up almost instantly? I thought the reason you couldn't very easily get into the BIOS was because it's UEFI and you need to prove you're a Windows administrator to gain access to the UEFI interface? Kind of like some SPAM filters they learn to not block an address if an email has been sent out to the address first... you've proved the address is legitimate by sending a message first, rather than it picking up an "unknown" address...

Comment: This [website](http://www.7tutorials.com/5-ways-boot-safe-mode-windows-8-windows-81) shows you the different ways you can access the Advanced Boot Menu in Windows 8 if need to.

Comment: In brief: A) Force a full shutdown by pressing Win+R keys and typing **shutdown -s -f -t 0**.    B) **Hold** the key for BIOS, F2 according to http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN114872/EN, **and then press the power key** while keeping F2 pressed.